# Linking error: selective static linking of libm.a in GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, static-linking

I want to selectively link `libm.a` statically, all the other libraries (`libc.so` included) dinamically. But if I use the math functions from `math.h`, it **almost always** fails to link correctly. Why? 
And why does it work sometimes? (For example if I only use `sqrt`, `fabs` or, strangely, `tanh`, it seems to link correctly)

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in sqrt tanh sin tan  
do
     echo "-----$i----------"
     sed "s/ciao/$i/" prova.c >provat.c
     gcc provat.c -fno-builtin -l:libm.a
     [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && { echo -n "$i(2.0)="; ./a.out; echo " OK!"; }
         echo
done
```

prova.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f", ciao(2.0));
    return 0;
}
```

If I run `myscript.sh`, I can see that `sqrt` and `tanh` give no problems. `sin` and `tan`, instead, fail to link:

```
$./myscript.sh
-----sqrt----------
sqrt(2.0)=1.414214 OK!

-----tanh----------
tanh(2.0)=0.964028 OK!

-----sin----------
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.a(s_sin.o): In function `__sin_ifunc':
(.text+0x4d42): undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.a(s_sin.o): In function `__cos_ifunc':
(.text+0x4da2): undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

-----tan----------
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.a(s_tan.o): In function `__tan_ifunc':
(.text+0x5782): undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand these error messages. Can somebody explain what happens? 
Why can't I link `libm.a` statically (and the rest dinamically)? And why does it work sometimes?

**Note:** I use the `-fno-builtin` flag to GCC, so that GCC doesn't use any of its builtin functions. So the problem is not there.

Comment: from https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1433347 `Either the entire implementation of the runtime is statically linked or none of it is statically linked.`

Comment: Can you explain me why is that? Is it explained in some documentation? Why does it work sometimes? Thank you

Comment: It is explained in the answer in the link I posted. What more do you need? If you link `libm.a` without other parts of static C library, you'll get unresolved symbols, because ABI is not complete.

Comment: I saw that link. It just states that fact very vaguely. Why does it work with `sqrt`, `fabs`, `tanh` then?

Comment: @KamilCuk you just posted a link to the first google result. You still haven't explained why  the `tanh` works and `tan` doesn't.

Comment: Any particular reason for all the restrictions? *-fno-builtin*, *-l:libm.a*? What are the versions for: your *OS*, *gcc*, *libc*, *ld*, ...?

Comment: -fno-builtin is necessary in this test otherwise gcc will use (already at compile time) its builtin functions for those math functions, instead of the ones from libm. This would defeats the purpose of the test. (I used Ubuntu 18, gcc 7).

Comment: I can reproduce it even without *-fno-builtin*. (*Ubtu 16*, *gcc 5.4*, *libc 2.23*).

Answer (score 5):

It's not very clear (to me) why the restriction (*libm.a* + *libc.so*) is necessary, so it smells like an *XY Problem*.

According to [[RedHat.Bugzilla]: Bug 1433347 - glibc: Selective static linking of libm.a fails due to unresolved _dl_x86_cpu_features symbol](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1433347) (pointed out by @KamilCuk):

> This is not supported.
>
> You would be mixing a static libm.a with future libc.so.6 and ld.so and that breaks the interdependencies between the core libraries which form "the implemetnation of the C runtime."
>
> Either the entire implementation of the runtime is statically linked or none of it is statically linked. You can't choose to link parts of it statically and not others because each part depends on the other to form a complete implementation. The math library is not a thin you can link against statically, it happens we have a libm.a, but that's an implementation detail.
>
> Please use '-static' for the entire application.

it seems like it's an unsupported configuration. That makes sense, but it's also a little bit confusing: even if *libc* and *libm* are **2 separate files** on disk (for each configuration: *static*, *shared*), they are **part of the same library** (*g**libc***), so:

- It's not *OK* to use half of a library statically built, and the other half as a shared object (some things that come into my mind are: *gcc*'s ***-fPIC*** flag, and also library's initialization)
- Of course, most of the times, a library **consists of a single file**, so the above bullet wouldn't apply (there's where the confusion comes from)

From the beginning, I suspected that it's some code that (detects and) uses (if present) some *CPU* capabilities (most likely to improve speed or accuracy), that:

- Is only used by some of the (trigonometric) functions (like *sin*, *cos*, but **not** *tanh*) - I'm just guessing here: based on how the function values are computed (e.g. *Taylor series*)
- It only happens when *libc* (*libm*) are in sync

I used this simple program.

*main.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#if !defined(FUNC)
#  define FUNC sqrt
#endif


int main() {
    double val = 3.141592;
    printf("func(%.06lf): %.06lf\n", val, FUNC(val));
    return 0;
}
```

Below it's a series of steps that I followed when looking into the problem:

1. Environment:

   > ```bash
   > [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q056415996]> ~/sopr.sh
   > *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
   >
   > [prompt]> uname -a
   > Linux cfati-ubtu16x64-0 4.15.0-51-generic #55~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 09:24:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   > [prompt]> gcc --version
   > gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
   > Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   > This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   > warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
   >
   > [prompt]> ldd --version
   > ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11) 2.23
   > Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   > This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   > warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
   > Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
   > [prompt]> ls
   > main.c
   > ```
2. The case when the 2 library parts (*libc* and *libm*) are in sync:

   > ```bash
   > [prompt]> gcc -fPIC main.c -DFUNC=sin -o sin_static.out -static -lm
   > [prompt]> ll sin_static.out
   > -rwxrwxr-x 1 cfati cfati 1007744 Jun 13 20:08 sin_static.out
   > [prompt]> ldd sin_static.out
   >         not a dynamic executable
   > [prompt]> ./sin_static.out
   > func(3.141592): 0.000001
   > [prompt]>
   > [prompt]> gcc -fPIC main.c -DFUNC=sin -o sin_mso.out -l:libm.so
   > [prompt]> ll sin_mso.out
   > -rwxrwxr-x 1 cfati cfati 8656 Jun 13 20:09 sin_mso.out
   > [prompt]> ldd sin_mso.out
   >         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc80ddd000)
   >         libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f999636b000)
   >         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9995fa1000)
   >         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9996674000)
   > [prompt]> ./sin_mso.out
   > func(3.141592): 0.000001
   > ```

   Everything works fine in both cases.
3. Switch to *libm.a* (for *sin* and *tanh*):

   > ```bash
   > [prompt]> gcc -fPIC main.c -DFUNC=sin -o sin_ma.out -l:libm.a
   > /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a(s_sin.o): In function `__cos':
   > (.text+0x3542): undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
   > /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a(s_sin.o): In function `__sin':
   > (.text+0x3572): undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
   > collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   > [prompt]> ll sin_ma.out
   > ls: cannot access 'sin_ma.out': No such file or directory
   > [prompt]>
   > [prompt]> gcc -fPIC main.c -DFUNC=tanh -o tanh_ma.out -l:libm.a
   > [prompt]> ll tanh_ma.out
   > -rwxrwxr-x 1 cfati cfati 12856 Jun 13 20:10 tanh_ma.out
   > [prompt]> ldd tanh_ma.out
   >         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcfa531000)
   >         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f124625c000)
   >         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1246626000)
   > [prompt]> ./tanh_ma.out
   > func(3.141592): 0.996272
   > ```

   As seen:

   - For *sin*, the linker complained (even **without *-fno-builtin***)
   - For *tanh*, things went fine

   From now on, I'm going to focus on **the case that doesn't work**.
4. Play a bit with the linker flags (`man ld` ([[die.linux]: ld(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld))):

   > ```bash
   > [prompt]> gcc -fPIC main.c -DFUNC=sin -o sin_ma_undefined.out -l:libm.a -Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols
   > /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a(s_sin.o): In function `__cos':
   > (.text+0x3542): warning: undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
   > /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a(s_sin.o): In function `__sin':
   > (.text+0x3572): warning: undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
   > [prompt]> ll sin_ma_undefined.out
   > -rwxrwxr-x 1 cfati cfati 104088 Jun 13 20:10 sin_ma_undefined.out
   > [prompt]> ldd sin_ma_undefined.out
   >         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff984b0000)
   >         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f274ad00000)
   >         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f274b0ca000)
   > [prompt]> ./sin_ma_undefined.out
   > Segmentation fault (core dumped)
   > ```

   It passed the link phase, but *segfault*ed at runtime (which was kind of expected).
5. Came across **[[Amper.Git]: open-source/glibc - Add _dl_x86_cpu_features to rtld_global](https://git.amper.me/open-source/glibc/commit/e2e4f56056adddc3c1efe676b40a4b4f2453103b)** (note that **none** of that is in the **official** *glibc*: [[GNU]: Index of /gnu/libc](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc)). It's some pretty heavy stuff there. I "borrowed" some and saved it.

   *_dl_x86_cpu_features.c*:

   ```c
   #if defined(_DL_X86_CPU_FEATURES__WORKAROUND)

   #  define FEATURE_INDEX_MAX 1


   enum {
       COMMON_CPUID_INDEX_1 = 0,
       COMMON_CPUID_INDEX_7,
       COMMON_CPUID_INDEX_80000001,        // for AMD
       // Keep the following line at the end.
       COMMON_CPUID_INDEX_MAX
   };


   struct cpu_features {
       enum cpu_features_kind  {
           arch_kind_unknown = 0,
           arch_kind_intel,
           arch_kind_amd,
           arch_kind_other
       } kind;
       int max_cpuid;
       struct cpuid_registers {
           unsigned int eax;
           unsigned int ebx;
           unsigned int ecx;
           unsigned int edx;
       } cpuid[COMMON_CPUID_INDEX_MAX];
       unsigned int family;
       unsigned int model;
       unsigned int feature[FEATURE_INDEX_MAX];
   };


   struct cpu_features _dl_x86_cpu_features;

   #endif
   ```

   `#include "_dl_x86_cpu_features.c"` also needs to be added in *main.c*:

   > ```bash
   > [prompt]> gcc -fPIC main.c -DFUNC=sin -D_DL_X86_CPU_FEATURES__WORKAROUND -o sin_ma_workaround.out -l:libm.a
   > [prompt]> ll sin_ma_workaround.out
   > -rwxrwxr-x 1 cfati cfati 104088 Jun 13 20:13 sin_ma_workaround.out
   > [prompt]> ldd sin_ma_workaround.out
   >         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff17b6c000)
   >         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5a992e5000)
   >         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5a996af000)
   > [prompt]> ./sin_ma_workaround.out
   > func(3.141592): 0.000001
   > ```

   Apparently, **it works** (at least in my environment)!!!

Although it did the trick for me (and probably it will be the same in your case), I still consider it a workaround (*gainarie*), and **I'm not aware of the full implications**. 
So, my advice is to go with (either one of) the recommended options (from step ***#2.***). 
But, it would be interesting to see how other compilers behave.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer.  I was curious about this behavior, but I guess it goes beyond my current abilities.  I struggled to follow your 5th point (I'm still a beginner), but I get all the rest.  Btw, I assure you that with GCC version 7.4.0, if you don't use the *-fno-builtin* flag, the compiler uses its built-in functions for all those math functions.

Comment: I tried *gcc 7.4.0*, but on *Cygwin*, and there the *-fno-builtin* isn't required too, in order to reproduce the failure. Bottom line, does the last step work in your scenario? Anyway, that's just a memory zone that gets populated during *libc* startup, so I guess it would be enough to pass a large enough buffer.

Comment: It certainly shed light on the issue. I voted it up.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you so much for your #5. It's the only solution on the whole internet that solves my problem of linking to libm.a For those cmake users out there, the trick is to compile and archive a libfixm.a from the source code in #5, and link_libraries(libm.a, libfixm.a) early in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @Hackless: Glad to hear that your problem got fixed!. Spread the word then! :)