# g++ failing to link statically when compiling to binary format: "skipping incompatible libm.a when searching for -lm"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, cross-compiling, ld

While attempting to write a kernel in C++, I've run into a peculiar issue.
When prompting g++ to compile even a very basic C++ file statically and to binary, it simply keeps skipping over the static math library (libm.a), ultimately failing to compile.

Attempting to compile a simple C++ file:

test.cpp

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

using this g++ command:

```
g++ -static test.cpp -Wl,--oformat=binary
```

I receive the following error output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
```

I am running Linux Mint Cinnamon V. 21 (Vanessa) on a VirtualBox VM.

In my attempt to narrow down the issue, I have also attempted to exclude the -static flag:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wl,--oformat=binary
```

Which results in a different error entirely:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libstdc++.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After thorough research, I was made aware that this could be caused by an incompatibility between 32-bit libraries and 64-bit files. Everything is supposed to be in 64 bit.
I did attempt to determine bitness of libm.a using file.

When using the file command on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a, I receive the following output:

```
libm.a: ASCII text
```

indicating neither bitness. This led me to conclude that perhaps the library is damaged and needs updating. After running sudo apt-get install libc6-dev, the issue persists, however.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Update:
I've opened libm.a in a text editor and the entire contents of the file are:

```
/* GNU ld script
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.35.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.a )
```

Update 2: apparently this is a linker script. Both referenced files `libm-2.35.a` and `libmvec.a` are present in my directory and are, according to objdump, 64-bit-versions.

Based on the compiler's error output, it seems that in my case, for whatever reason, g++ (or more specifically, ld) fails to use this linker script. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Presumably you need to tell the compiler to skip the standard libraries.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not following a tutorial in particular, though I am using [the osdev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), [this youtube series](https://youtu.be/Lke3QOytgcQ?list=PLmlvkUN3-1MNKwINqdCDtTdNDjfBmWcZA), and [this document](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) as resources. good call on the standard libraries, though I believe C++ relies on libm and libstdc++ being linked for object oriented features to be used.

Comment: Depends on what you call "OO features". I wouldn't expect them to work with raw binary output.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I haven't thought about this. how so? I was under the impression that C++ code (utilising e.g. classes and instances) could be compiled to raw binary format, retaining full functionality, if libm and libstdc++ were linked statically.

Comment: I might be wrong. I'd wait for another opinion.

Comment: Try open it in a text editor and see what kind of ASCII text it contains.

Comment: @n.m. good call. I just did that and updated the post in accordance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that it is not normally possible to statically link C++ code involving object oriented features into a fully functional binary file, as libm.a can apparently be linked to ELF only.

besides: even the static version of glibc, which is also required, references other dynamic libraries, making it useless for kernel code.

there might be some sort of workaround, but it seems that g++ does not support this functionality by default.

Comment: Of course you can static link all glibc, in fact it is faster than dynamic in C++ by a lot. -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc but there are bugs there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415996/linking-error-selective-static-linking-of-libm-a-in-gcc it requires -static, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1433347